# Angular 4.4: Any way to create HttpClient based on Fetch?

Tags: angular, httpclient, fetch-api, angular-http-interceptors

Angular 4.4

I need to use **fetch** api instead of Angular's HttpClient in my services to be able to use those services(pure javascript classes) even out of Angular for other projects.

So I was thinking it would be as easy as extending a simple javascript class which is using fetch api and adding @Injectable decorator to the child class.

Here is an example of service:(In this module I don't want to be depend on Angular at all because this module might be used in a React project too)

```js
export class SampleServiceBase {
    constructor() {}

    getCompanies() {
        return fetch('https://example.com/companies');
    }
}
```

And here is the Angular wrapper of the service:

```js
@Injectable()
export class SampleService extends SampleServiceBase {
    getCompanies():any {
        return Observable.create(() => fromPromise(super.getCompanies()));
    }
}
```

But it turned out that I cannot benefit from some features of Angular HttpClient like **HttpInteceptors**.

So my question is that if there is any way to wrap fetch api into HttpClient api in Angular?

Comment: Why don't you extend the HttpClient and overwrite the methods that you need?
https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient